# Remove NA from plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following table that I want to plot in R

```
     A    B    C  NA
0   500  200  200 0
```

This table is generated from a variable. I had previously removed the NAs using `data<-data[!(data$pid3==""),]`

If I use the `plot()` function with this variable, the NA and "" shows up in the plot. How do I get rid of this in the plot?

Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Is ``NA``/Are ``NAs`` here only a colname with 0 as value?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `""` and `NA` in R:

```
> is.na("")
[1] FALSE
> is.na(NA)
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to remove NAs, you should use something like this:

```
data <- data[!is.na(data$pid3),]
```

(It may be a good idea to remove empty strings as well, so you can run the command above in addition to your previous filtering step.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I was able to achieve this using the `ggplot2` package.

I generate the table using

```
table <- data %>% group_by(pid3) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Then I plot using `ggplot2`

```r
ggplot(table, aes(x = pid3, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + theme_classic()
```

Comment: What is `%<%`? That looks similar to `magrittr`'s `%>%` operator, but is not the same. (If it's a typo, it's generally best -- in both questions and answers -- to use code from your console or source file after testing/using it, as otherwise it is possibly to give code that is syntactically invalid.)